# Why do I get ECONNREFUSED in the terminal, but not the browser?

Tags: node.js, api, https, query-string, econnrefused

I have a very simple nodejs program that I am using to demonstrate communication with the Alchemer API.  Whenever I run the following code, an error is thrown with the code `ECONNREFUSED`.  However, when I copy the same url into the browser or Postman, it works just fine.

Note- One odd thing I noticed, in the error's stack-trace (see below), it says the address is 127.0.0.1, even though I'm clearly not making a request to my localhost...

### Nodejs Snippet

```
require('dotenv').config();
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

console.log('Formulating query string...');

const params = {
    api_token: process.env.API_TOKEN,
    api_token_secret: process.env.API_TOKEN_SECRET
};

const reqArgs = querystring.stringify(params);

console.log('Query string: ', reqArgs);

const reqOptions  = {
    url: 'https://api.alchemer.com',
    path: '/v5/survey?' + reqArgs,
}

console.log('Test Url: ', reqOptions.url + reqOptions.path); // THIS WORKS IN THE 
BROWSER / POSTMAN
console.log('Getting data...');

https.request(reqOptions, resp => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('error', err => {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Request complete.');
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

### Error Observed

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443
}
```

Comment: Try to explicitly set the `host` property to `https://api.alchemer.com` in  the `reqOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL does not appear to be the correct property name for setting your URL in the request options, according to the [https.requests](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback%5D) doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback).

Consider changing the `url` key on your `reqOptions` to `hostname` or `host`

```js
const reqOptions  = {
    hostname: 'https://api.alchemer.com',
    path: '/v5/survey?' + reqArgs,
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This resolved my ECONNREFUSED error, but now I am receiving a ECONNRESET after a several second delay.  As I mentioned, the generated url works just fine in the browser and postman, yet this nodejs library keeps giving me new errors...